# Batch pipeline is not working in azure data factory

Tags: c#, azure, azure-data-factory

I create a pipeline having 5 Activity. If anyone of the activity will fail it should run the batch process. So in the fail scenario, I have pointed to the batch process.
Problem is when I point all Activity to batch process it is not triggering but when I removed all activity and point only one activity, It starts working.
I don't know what is the issue.
For more details, Please find the screenshots.

[In this image if any one of the activity will fail, then email should trigger. But its not working. Please check another image also.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/491It.png)

[while in this image its working as expected.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5YdOo.png)

Please can someone look into this.

Answer (score 0):

Actually in the first image, the email will trigger when all the activities fail. The joined line indicates AND logic.

If you want to make it send email once any of the activities fails, you can try to add an [ExecutePipeline activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/control-flow-execute-pipeline-activity), and set `waitOnCompletion` as `true`, and reference your pipeline in the executePipeline activity.